# `<ul>` is not floating all the way in container

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

So i have not seen this problem before, so im not quite sure what to ask but..
I have a menu with is inside a container, i want it to float right, it does but just not all the way, i cant figure what is stopping it. so i need a little help here?

My `<ul>` is floating right like this:

```
nav > div div > div > ul.nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

but i think it eayser to see in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/naicJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an element in the `.top-bar` is too high. Specifically the `.top-bar .lang`. This has a padding for the top of 1px, causing it to overflow out of it's container. There are two ways to solve this.

The best way is to change the padding on `.top-bar .lang`.

```
.top-bar .lang {
    padding: 0 10px; // this was 1px 10px 0
    font-size: 9px;
    border-right: solid 1px #2d2d2d;
}
```

And the easier way is:

```
.top-bar .container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As this causes the overflowing content to be hidden.

All that remains then is to remove the padding on the right side of the div `collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse`.

Comment: So i took yours, but in stead of editing the padding to `0 10px` i add a `line-height: 20px` instead, that did the trick and didn't have to move the lang that one pixel closer to the top :) So thank you

Comment: Ah, ofcourse. Option 3 ;-) That helps as well. It does the same as the first option, it makes the div slightly less high. Good to hear that it's solved then!

Answer (score 1):

You need two changes - 
 Add `clear: right;` style in `ul.nav`. I am writing the updated CSS -

```
nav > div div > div > ul.nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    z-index: 6;
    clear: right;
}
```

Also, add the following CSS -

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem coming from the following code.

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px)
   .container {
   width: 1170px;
 }
```

Your above code will assign the `width:1170px` to all the monitors which is more than 1200px. It means if I open your code in 1366px monitor, I can see the container with only 1170px;

Change your code according to your needs.

Comment: Maybe it is just me that not understand what you are saying, but i cant see what this has to do with my question? - The above css comes from twitter bootstrap and is only on the container, my problem lays in the `<ul>`wich is not floating all the way to right inside the container